# phpmailer with inline image and attachment in Thunderbird

Tags: email, attachment, phpmailer

I using **phpmailer** to send mail but I have a problem with Thunderbird with 'inline images' and 'attachment file' !

If I use **only** 'attachment file' I can see the attachment icon in Thunderbird, but with both, 'inline images' and 'attachment file' in the mail, the attachment icon **is not showed in Thunderbird** (works fine with all other webmail like gmail, hotmail, yahoo, etc...)

I already checked these posts

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=2245979

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=682226

but I can not solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I had a similary problem.

Upgrade to the last version of PHP Mailer (v5.2.1).

In the AddAttachment(arg1,arg2) dont forget to precise the arg2.